# I have a problem with 'Int' Object is not iterable

Tags: python, object, integer, pyautogui, iterable

I have a problem with integer object

I tried:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    pyautogui.write(i)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(1)
```

i expected it to say:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Answer (score 1):

The `write` function [expects a string](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html?highlight=write#the-write-function):

> The primary keyboard function is `write()`. This function will type the **characters in the string that is passed**

Turn `i` into a string first:

```
pyautogui.write(str(i))
```